# Robot framework 'Run Keyword If' expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Tags: robotframework

```
 Run Keyword If    '${auditTrailFromState}'!='<n/a>' AND '${auditTrailToState}'!='<n/a>' AND '${auditTrailUser}'!='<n/a>'
/    Add Auditing Expectations    ${auditTrailFromState}    ${auditTrailToState}    ${auditTrailUser}
/    AND    Open Auditing Event Queue
/    AND    Verify Auditing Expectations
```

getting error 
'Run Keyword If' expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved as below

```
[Arguments]    ${auditTrailFromState}    ${auditTrailToState}    ${auditTrailUser}
Run Keyword If    '${auditTrailFromState}'!='<n/a>'
...    Run Keywords
...    Define Auditing Event Queue
...    AND    Add Auditing Expectations    ${auditTrailFromState}    ${auditTrailToState}    ${auditTrailUser}
...    AND    Open Auditing Event Queue
...    AND    Verify Auditing Expectations
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you did ..can you explain

Comment: Actually I was trying to run multiple keywords if given condition is true.. to do that we have to use "Run Keywords" keyword and then combine multiple keywords using "And" .. like above if '${auditTrailFromState}'!='<n/a>' result true then it will run all the keywords- 
...    Run Keywords
...    Define Auditing Event Queue
...    AND    Add Auditing Expectations    ${auditTrailFromState}    ${auditTrailToState}    ${auditTrailUser}
...    AND    Open Auditing Event Queue
...    AND    Verify Auditing Expectations